# Executing a native query that return different objects with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following query:

```
SELECT City.*, User.*
FROM City,User
```

and I have an entityManager Object. So it is possible to execute this query and the entityManager returns me a list of [City,User]?

because I only see that exists this method: createNativeQuery(String, Class).

Comment: it will give you all possible combinations of records from table CITY with User table. I think that is not required to you.

Comment: see [Resultset Mapping With Two Entities](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/ResultsetMappingWithTwoEntities.htm)